# ImageMagick frame a picture with border color from a file

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to add a frame/border to a picture where border "color" comes from a file. 
The file can be found here https://storage.googleapis.com/ramki-opticlan/paspartu_small.jpg

I think Imagemagick can't do that exaclty, so my idea was to create a new background with the desired dimensions and place the image on top of it.

```
#creates the background
convert -size ${PICTURE_WIDTH}x${PICTURE_HEIGHT} tile:paspartu_small.jpg background.jpg

# places one on top of each other
convert background.jpg picture_that_needs_to_be_framed.jpg -gravity center -region +0-0 -composite -matte result.jpg
```

My problem is that I cannot calculate the dimentions of the background and correctly adjust the image position without breaking the image aspect ratio.
If someone can help me create a script to calculate those positions, I would be very grateful.

Let's take this case for example:

- my picture is 600x500px
- top border has to be 40px
- right border has to be 50px
- bottom border has to be 60px
- left border has to be 50px

Hopefully, it's understandable what I am trying to accomplish.
Cheers

I am using IM7

Comment: It is always a good idea to include your IM version and programming laungage as that can have an effect on the answer. What is the -region +0-0 supposed to do? With V7 you can probably do everything in one line; whereas V6 you would need two or three lines.

Comment: i edited my post, thanks. Was afk sorry for the delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ImageMagick v7+, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOP=40
RIGHT=50
BOTTOM=60
LEFT=50
PICTURE="artwork.jpg"
BACKGROUND="background.jpg"

magick "$PICTURE" \
       -size "%[fx:w+${LEFT}+${RIGHT}]"x"%[fx:h+${TOP}+${BOTTOM}]" tile:"$BACKGROUND" \
       +swap -geometry +${LEFT}+${TOP} -composite result.jpg
```

---

If you have ImageMagick v6, this should do what you want and be pretty easy to customise:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOP=40
RIGHT=50
BOTTOM=60
LEFT=50
PICTURE="artwork.jpg"
BACKGROUND="background.jpg"

# Get width and height of picture
read w h < <(convert "$PICTURE" -format "%w %h" info:)

((NEW_W=w+LEFT+RIGHT))
((NEW_H=h+TOP+BOTTOM))

convert -size ${NEW_W}x${NEW_H} tile:"$BACKGROUND" \
        "$PICTURE" -geometry +${LEFT}+${TOP} -composite result.jpg
```

So, if I start with this:

[image]

I end up with this:

[image]

Comment: oh my lord ... that is just amazing. Thanks a lot for the help, i would never manage to do this by myself. You rock !

Comment: It may not be possible to maintain output aspect ratio equal to input aspect ratio by adding arbitrary border sizes. Mark Setchell has shown the command below to add the borders of the size you want. The input is 600x500 or w/h aspect of 1.2. But the output is 700x600 or a w/h aspect of 1.167. So either you need to accept the difference in aspect ratio, or you need to add different size borders to achieve the same aspect ratio, or you must resize the resulting image in a way that will distort it to maintain the desired aspect ratio.

Comment: @fmw42 Agreed, however I took the question to mean that the topmost image must remain undistorted and the borders are in accordance with the spevified thicknesses - which, admittedly, will result in the overall aspect ratio (incl bordeers) changing.